# Remove old values from array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a JavaScript array like below,

```
 var stack=array();
 stack[0]=1;
 stack[1]=10;
 stack[5]=5;
 ------------
 ------------
 stack[50]=15;
 stack[55]=5; etc
```

I only need last **n** elements from this array,I mean if n=2,
Then my result like

```
 stack[0]=15;
 stack[1]=5;
```

How to unset old values from array using JavaScript keeping needed elements?

Answer (score 3):

Edit: based on the OP's subsequent comments, it looks like you want one of my last two options below (I leave the others here for educational purposes).

To get the last N elements (lets use 2 in these examples), you have these options depending upon whether you want to remove everything else from the original array, remove just the last N from the original array or make a copy of the last N from the original array.  And, it also depends upon whether your array is spare or not (which your example kind of looks like it might be).

Basically, your friends here are the array operations `.splice()` and `.slice()`.  `.splice()` changes the original array.  `.slice()` copies elements from the original array.

References for [`.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Here are some of your options (depending upon exactly what you want to do):

```
// remove all elements except the last 2 from the array
stack.splice(0, stack.length -2);
```

or

```
// return a new array of just the last two elements
// removes them from the original array too
var lastElements = stack.splice(-2, 2);
```

or

```
// return a copy of just the first two items in the array (
// leaves original array unchanged
var lastElements = stack.slice(-2);
```

or

If your array is sparse and you want to collect the last N elements that actually exist, then you can iterate over it, collecting elements that exist:

```
var collection = [];
for (i = stack.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (stack[i] !== undefined) {
        collection.unshift(stack[i]);
        if (collection.length == 2) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or

If you don't require IE8 support or will install a polyfill for `Array.prototype.filter` and you just want a copy of the last two elements, you can shorten the previous option to this:

```
stack = stack.filter(function(item) {return item !== undefined}).slice(-2);
```

Demo of all methods: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/f7LrA/

Comment: Why the downvote (looks like maybe a serial downvoter since everything got downvoted)?  I was just trying to cover the various options since the OP didn't explain exactly what they're after (modifying the original array or not, sparse or not).

Comment: That isn't what "serial downvoting" is. I downvoted all the answers because they were all wrong, and that's *exactly* what downvoting is for.

Comment: @meagar - decent downvoters explain why they downvoted.  How is my answer wrong?

Comment: Your answer eventually gets around to being *not wrong*, but it's still not optimal. You've reinvented the `filter` wheel. And no, "decent" downvoters do not comment. Nobody owes you a comment with a downvote, that isn't how voting works. If you read the comments OP is leaving on answers, you can figure out why they are being downvoted.

Comment: @meagar - so you downvoted my answer because you think it's less elegant than yours?  Geez - that's not what downvotes are for.  The OP left a lot of details unclear so I tried to educate them on the possibilities they could use.  If you're interested in helping the best content appear on StackOverflow and you see an answer that you think is wrong, you explain why.  That helps everyone, including the OP, the person who wrote the answer and the readers.  Just clicking off a bunch of downvotes doesn't help the community near as much.

Comment: Downvotes are for expressing disagreement with the technical merit of a question, yes. If you post bubble sort in response to "how do I sort an array", you deserve downvotes. I admit I was overly hasty in downvoting your answer, I assumed that you had jumped on the "FGITW USE SPLICE" train like everybody else, and missing the final case where you cover sparse arrays.

Comment: @meagar - and they are a lot more valuable to everyone if you explain why you think it deserves a downvote.

Comment: On every answer except yours (and the link-only answer which isn't useful at all) there was an existing comment by the author explicitly stating why the answer was wrong.

Comment: @meagar - also in `.filter()` still isn't supported by IE 8 which some people want to support.  I don't blindly assume in my answers that everyone has abandoned IE 8 or knows about polyfills.

Comment: The solution is a `filter` polyfill, not to avoid `filter`.

Comment: @meagar - that is your opinion.  If you're working on projects where some people contributing are using the wrong way of iterating arrays, polyfills on the array object can cause iteration problems.

Comment: @shin - based on your comments, I think you want one of my last two options here.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to achieve what you want in this context.

Try,

```
stack = stack.slice(stack.length - n , stack.length)
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/v3pfM/)

Comment: But indexes are not in the order,  http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/MtJZ3/, I got undefined

Comment: @shin Yes, that's obvious. You have not filled that cell of the array with any values. If you want to do as you expected, traverse the array reversely.

Comment: is possible to make the indexes in the order?

Answer (score 1):

You think your array doesn't use continuous keys, but it does. The values at the indices you have not explicitly assigned to are simply `undefined`.

You need to remove the `undefined` elements from your array, and then slice the result:

```
var stack = [];
var n=2;

stack[0]=1;
stack[1]=10;
stack[2]=5;
stack[7]=15;
stack[9]=5; 

// Here, stack == [1, 10, 5, undefined × 4, 15, undefined × 1, 5]

// map stack to a new array, omitting "falsy" values
stack = stack.filter(function (v) { return v; });

// Now stack == [1, 10, 5, 15, 5]

stack = stack.slice(stack.length - n , stack.length)

console.log(stack[0]); // 15
console.log(stack[1]); // 5
```

This omits any falsy value; if you want to remove only the `undefined` elements...

```
stack = stack.filter(function (v) { return v !== undefined; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice` to change the array

```
stack.splice(2, stack.length - 2);
```

You can use `slice` to get new array

```
var newStack = stack.slice(0, 2);
```

Comment: I tried slice  http://jsfiddle.net/shijin/YQpD2/  But the result was not the expected

Comment: @FizerKhan - It was unfair a -1 - That I have rectified